# Alternative to Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad() and ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom()?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm migrating a .Net 4.x application to .Net 6, but the above methods are now deprecated and throw an exception if called. What are the alternatives?

This is the code, which gets passed a list of assembly filenames, and loads any assemblies found to have a certain assembly-level attribute in AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve +=
    (s, e) => Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(e.Name);

foreach (var assemblyFile in assemblyFilenames)
{
    var reflectionOnlyAssembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom(assemblyFile);
    if (FoundOurCustomAttr(reflectionOnlyAssembly))
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyFile);
        ProcessAssembly(assembly);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make another `AppDomain` then unload it?

Comment: @Charlieface I've just had a look and it seems that .Net core apps don't support creation of app domains unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is using [MetadataLoadContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.metadataloadcontext?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)  package.

```
var paths = new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles(RuntimeEnvironment.GetRuntimeDirectory(), "*.dll"));
paths.AddRange(assemblyFilenames);

var resolver = new PathAssemblyResolver(paths);
var ctx = new MetadataLoadContext(resolver);
foreach (var assemblyFile in assemblyFilenames)
{
    var assembly = ctx.LoadFromAssemblyPath(assemblyFile);
    foreach(var a in assembly.CustomAttributes)
        // a.AttributeType
}
```

Comment: Thanks. After loading an assembly using ctx.LoadFromAssemblyPath() and checking if it contains my custom attribute, do I then have to use `var assembly2 = Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyFile);' to load that assembly into my app domain? Or is there some way to copy/move the assembly from the context? The MS documentation isn't great in this area!

Comment: Yes you need to use Assembly.LoadFrom.

Answer (score -1):

Could maybe the methods [Assembly.Load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.load?view=net-6.0) and [Assembly.LoadFrom](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom?view=net-6.0) be a valid option?

Comment: I was hoping to avoid this route. The 'ReflectionOnly' methods were nice in that they didn't load the assemblies into the app domain. From what I can understand it was like a temporary load to peek into the assemblies using reflection.

Comment: For people that are using `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad` on purpose, moving to `Assembly.Load` is usually not an option.